# Tensorflow Change Output Image Size to Be Different From Training Input Size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to modify a tensorflow project from GitHub so that I can train with 64x64 images, but then create larger output images for example 384x384 output images. When I change the output image size (via command line) I get this error:

Dimensions must be equal, but are 384 and 64 for 'Mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,384,384,3], [21,64,64,3].

It has to do with this line in the code:

```
self.contextual_loss = tf.reduce_sum(
        tf.contrib.layers.flatten(
            tf.abs(tf.mul(self.mask, self.G) - tf.mul(self.mask, self.images))), 1)
```

I have tried changing tf.mul() to tf.matmul() and still get a similar error. I have also tried tf.reshape() which gives me a different error. Thanks for any help.

```
def build_model(self):
    self.images = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, [None] + self.image_shape, name='real_images')

    self.sample_images= tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, [None] + self.image_shape, name='sample_images')
    self.z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.z_dim], name='z')
    self.z_sum = tf.histogram_summary("z", self.z)

    self.G = self.generator(self.z)
    self.D, self.D_logits = self.discriminator(self.images)

    self.sampler = self.sampler(self.z)
    self.D_, self.D_logits_ = self.discriminator(self.G, reuse=False)

    self.d_sum = tf.histogram_summary("d", self.D)
    self.d__sum = tf.histogram_summary("d_", self.D_)
    self.G_sum = tf.image_summary("G", self.G)

    self.d_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.D_logits,
                                                tf.ones_like(self.D)))
    self.d_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.D_logits_,
                                                tf.zeros_like(self.D_)))
    self.g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.D_logits_,
                                                tf.ones_like(self.D_)))

    self.d_loss_real_sum = tf.scalar_summary("d_loss_real", self.d_loss_real)
    self.d_loss_fake_sum = tf.scalar_summary("d_loss_fake", self.d_loss_fake)

    self.d_loss = self.d_loss_real + self.d_loss_fake

    self.g_loss_sum = tf.scalar_summary("g_loss", self.g_loss)
    self.d_loss_sum = tf.scalar_summary("d_loss", self.d_loss)

    t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

    self.d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'd_' in var.name]
    self.g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name]

    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)

    # Completion.
    self.mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + self.image_shape, name='mask')
    self.contextual_loss = tf.reduce_sum(
        tf.contrib.layers.flatten(
            tf.abs(tf.mul(self.mask, self.G) - tf.mul(self.mask, self.images))), 1)
    self.perceptual_loss = self.g_loss
    self.complete_loss = self.contextual_loss + self.lam*self.perceptual_loss
    self.grad_complete_loss = tf.gradients(self.complete_loss, self.z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.mul()` and  `tf.matmul()` produce different results. The former is an entrywise multiplication, while the latter is a matrix multiplication.

In the line that raised the error, you have the following two expressions:

```
tf.mul(self.mask, self.G)

tf.mul(self.mask, self.images)
```

Since both `self.mask` and `self.images` have exactly the same shape (defined in the placeholder as `[None] + self.image_shape`), I am guessing that the problem is in

```
tf.mul(self.mask, self.G)
```

You changed the dimension of the image, but you also need to change the dimension of `self.G` to match those of the image. According to the error it seems that you didn't change them (as their shape is [21,64,64,3]).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very new to both tensorflow and python but I have also tried this to reshape G and got this error: 

tf.reshape(self.G, self.image_shape)

but this gives me an error

Cannot reshape a tensor with 258048 elements to shape [384,384,3] (442368 elements) for 'Reshape_4' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [21,64,64,3], [3].

Comment: Sorry for how ugly the comment is above, apparently there's no way to add line breaks in comments now

Comment: In order to reshape self.G, the product of all dimensions of self.G and self.image_shape should be the same. For example, [2,2,2,2] and [4,1,4,1], both have product 16. In your case the product is not the same (the products are 442368 and 258048).

Comment: Continuing the comment: I don't think that reshape is the solution here. It seems that even though you changed the dimensions of the input (to images of height and width of 384), the dimensions of self.G stayed unchanged. In your code, self.G is defined through the line self.G = self.generator(self.z), so maybe you can check inside the code of self.generator how to change the dimensions.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help I really appreciate it. I'll try that